# click button in IE with VBA (excel 2016)

Tags: html, vba

I would like to click on a Save button but cannot reference it correctly for VBA to find it on webpage.  I have attached HTML Code in an image, I blacked out a couple parts. I have searched online and tried numerous callouts to gain access to this button but VBA still can't find it. Using DOM explorer shows the button as the blue highlighted line in the image.

Can I SendKeys("TAB") until I reach the button and then send a generic click action or do I have to reference the element by name to click on it? How do I reference this Save button? I appreciate your help.

[HTML Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPQT9.png)

**HTML**

```
<html> 
<head>...</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" cols="*" frameBorder="no" frameSpacing="0" › <frame srcar frameBorder="NO" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="auto">
    <frame src="" frameBorder="NO" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="auto">
    <html> 
    <head>...</head>

    <body aLink="white" onload="readValues(0)" onresize="null">
        <form name="frmRptRetrieval" action="" encType="" mehotd="post">
        <table width="100%" height="5%" bgColor="•191667" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">...</table>
        <table width="100%" align="center" border="0">...</table>
        <img width="20" height="20" alt="notification.gif" src="../images/notification.gif"></img>
        <font color="green">Report Retrieval Query saved successfully.</font>
        <table width="780" align="center" border="0">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td align="left" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
                    <table width="100%" align="center" border="0">
                      <tbody>  
                        <tr vAlign="top">...</tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1" › <a href="javascript:doSubmit();" shape="">
                             <img height="18" src="../images/btn_Save.gif" border="0"></img>
                                </a>
                                <a href="javascript:clearAll();" shape="">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     objIE.navigate "YOUR_URL"
objIE.navigate objIE.document.frames(0).document.getelementsbyname("frmRptRetrieval")(0).document.getelementsbytagname("a")(XXXX).href
```

Now : Your job is to find the position of your button in the list of elements that have the tagname "a" and replace XXXX by this position-1 (because index).

Comment: I will try this and let you know if I get it working. Thanks.